# PHP CodeIgniter - use same functions for different controllers - minimize repetition

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the same variables on different controllers that are sent to my view like this:

**Controller A**

```
$data['priv_information'] = $this->m_user_group->get_priv_information();
$data['priv_customer'] = $this->m_user_group->get_priv_customer();
$data['priv_new_model'] = $this->m_user_group->get_priv_new_model();
$data['priv_price'] = $this->m_user_group->get_priv_price();
$data['priv_masspro'] = $this->m_user_group->get_priv_masspro();
$data['priv_product'] = $this->m_user_group->get_priv_product();
$data['priv_calendar'] = $this->m_user_group->get_priv_calendar();
$data['priv_maintenance'] = $this->m_user_group->get_priv_maintenance();
$this->load->view($this->template, $data);
```

**Controller B**

```
$data['priv_information'] = $this->m_user_group->get_priv_information();
$data['priv_customer'] = $this->m_user_group->get_priv_customer();
$data['priv_new_model'] = $this->m_user_group->get_priv_new_model();
$data['priv_price'] = $this->m_user_group->get_priv_price();
$data['priv_masspro'] = $this->m_user_group->get_priv_masspro();
$data['priv_product'] = $this->m_user_group->get_priv_product();
$data['priv_calendar'] = $this->m_user_group->get_priv_calendar();
$data['priv_maintenance'] = $this->m_user_group->get_priv_maintenance();
$this->load->view($this->template, $data);
```

Doing it this way, I always have to copy and paste the same code to other controllers. I have no problem doing this. However, my big problem is when I need to modify one variable. I have to re-copy - and paste the same code in others controller multiple times. How do I solve this problem to minimize repetition?.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Create a function that will take two arguments - reference to $data array(it must be reference!) and the second one that will be object which "$this->m_user_group" returns. Place this function in some helper class. It may be static.

Comment: make a parent class controller, have a common setup method for your data and have both A and B extend that parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a lib :

In application/libraries create Tools.php (or whatever you want)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Tools
{
  protected $ci;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance(); 
    }

    public function buildData()
    {
       $this->ci->load->model('m_user');
       $data['priv_information'] = $this->ci->m_user_group->get_priv_information(); 
       $data['priv_customer'] = $this->ci->m_user_group->get_priv_customer();   
       $data['priv_new_model'] = $this->ci->m_user_group->get_priv_new_model();  
       $data['priv_price'] = $this->ci->m_user_group->get_priv_price();    
       $data['priv_masspro'] = $this->ci->m_user_group->get_priv_masspro();    
       $data['priv_product'] = $this->ci->m_user_group->get_priv_product();
       $data['priv_calendar'] = $this->ci->m_user_group->get_priv_calendar();
       $data['priv_maintenance'] = $this->ci->m_user_group->get_priv_maintenance();

       return $data;
    }

}
```

And then in your controllers :

```
 $this->load->library("tools");
 $data = $this->tools->buildData();
 $this->load->view($this->template, $data);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would first place whatever array you want to share in a parent controller inside your `core` directory:

```
//located in application/core/MY_Parent_Controller.php

class MY_Parent_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public $shared_data;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->shared_data = array(
            'priv_information' => $this->m_user_group->get_priv_information(),
            'priv_customer' => $this->m_user_group->get_priv_customer(),
            'priv_new_model' => $this->m_user_group->get_priv_new_model(),
            'priv_price' => $this->m_user_group->get_priv_price(),
            'priv_masspro' => $this->m_user_group->get_priv_masspro(),
            'priv_product' => $this->m_user_group->get_priv_product(),
            'priv_calendar' => $this->m_user_group->get_priv_calendar(),
            'priv_maintenance' => $this->m_user_group->get_priv_maintenance()
        );
    }
}
```

Then Controller A (inside your regular `controllers` directory) would extend from the parent

```
//located in application/controllers/ContollerA.php

class ContollerA extends MY_Parent_Controller{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function other(){
        $this->shared_data['priv_information'] = 'other info here';
        $this->load->view($this->template, $this->shared_data);
    }

    function another(){
        $this->shared_data['priv_new_model'] = 'other info here';
        $this->load->view($this->template, $this->shared_data);
    }

}
```

And Controller B (inside your regular `controllers` directory) would extend from the parent as well

```
//located in application/controllers/ContollerB.php

class ContollerB extends MY_Parent_Controller{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function other(){
        $this->shared_data['priv_information'] = 'other info here';
        $this->load->view($this->template, $this->shared_data);
    }

    function another(){
        $this->shared_data['priv_new_model'] = 'other info here';
        $this->load->view($this->template, $this->shared_data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the code in a class that extends `MY_Controller` and overloads the methods that you need. Be sure to call the parent's function in your controller.

`application/core/MY_Child_class.php`

```
class MY_Child_class extends MY_Controller {

    public function index() {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

`application/controllers/your_controller.php`

```
class Your_controller extends MY_Child_class {
    public function index() {
        parent::index();
        // controller specific code here
    }
}
```

Hopefully you can apply this concept to you system.

Answer (score 0):

its all from the same model. so just make a method in that model and then call it. this also keeps the code in the same place instead of spread out in different places.

controller

```
// get the data, if there is an error show appropriate view
if( ! $data = $this->m_user_group->returnCustomer() ){

    $this->showError() ; }

else { $this->load->view($this->template, $data); }
```

in m_user_group model you could just do this:

```
function returnCustomer(){

$data['priv_information'] = $this->get_priv_information();
$data['priv_customer'] = $this->get_priv_customer();
$data['priv_new_model'] = $this->get_priv_new_model();
$data['priv_price'] = $this->get_priv_price();
$data['priv_masspro'] = $this->get_priv_masspro();
$data['priv_product'] = $this->get_priv_product();
$data['priv_calendar'] = $this->get_priv_calendar();
$data['priv_maintenance'] = $this->get_priv_maintenance();

return $data ; 

}
```

however **that is bad because whenever you are querying a database there should be error checking**. you then have a few choices - like create a default if no value comes back

```
function returnCustomer(){

if( ! $data['priv_information'] = $this->get_priv_information() ){

$data['priv_information'] = 'some default value' ; }

// etc etc
```

or if every db call has to work then return false if there is an error

```
function returnCustomer(){

if( ! $data['priv_information'] = $this->get_priv_information() ){

  return false ; }

// etc etc
```